# Yaml , counting lines including blank lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I am parsing a yaml file and searching for specific values, after the search matches i want to get the line number and print it. I managed to do exactly that but the major problem is that while parsing the yaml file using `YAML.LOAD` , the blank lines are ignored. 
i can count the rest of the lines using keys i.e. 1 key per line but i an unable to count blank lines. please help, been stuck with this for a few days now.

this is how my code looks like:

```
hash = YAML.load(IO.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'en.yml')))
def recursive_hash_to_yml_string(input, hash, depth = 0)
  hash.keys.each do |search| 
    @count = @count + 1 
    if hash[search].is_a?(String) && hash[search] == input
      @yml_array.push(@count)  
    elsif hash[search].is_a?(Hash)
      recursive_hash_to_yml_string(input, hash[search], depth + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Throwing away unneeded stuff (empty lines, comments) goes hand in hand with parsing. Why not do the counting in a second run?

Comment: the problem is where am i supposed to put the count.. since while parsing as YAMl, the whole file is a big hash and there is no trace of empty lines. i was thinking about modyfying the load method for yaml in the library but the library files became a bit too much confusing for me.. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Wukerplank - parsing a file should ignore blank lines. You might want to think about finding the line number using a different approach.

Perhaps you don't need to parse the YAML at all. If you are just searching the file for some matching text and returning the line number, maybe you'd manage better reading each line of the file using [`File.each_line`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-each_line).

You could iterate over each line in the file until you found a match and then do something with the line number.

Comment: i tried using this approach, but the problem is i have to match the values of hashes in the file and find out its occurances in the rest of the file. even after trying various ways to match it, it doesnt match the exact keys.eg: if i want to find _may_ it simply find may in sentences too instead of just may. and the file also contains some single & double quoted keys as well. which makes it hard to match.

Comment: you could get around these issues with some clever regex (i.e /^may:/)